# CSS Rule, Never seen before

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ok, looking at some code in a CSS Stylesheet assigned to a project, I noticed this:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

What does this bit do??  What elements does it effect exactly??  Strange, never heard tell of using the asterisks as a selector or whatever it is supposed to be for.  What does the asterisk do exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` affects (I should say "represents the qualified name of") *all* elements.  Per spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector

Comment: @Solomon Closson As an aside, it's generally recommended now not to use `*` to reset things like margin and padding, as it has irreversible effects on some elements like form inputs. There are some more forgiving "resets" out there that remove margin and padding from a whole bunch of elements while leaving out the elements that would be negatively impacted.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I'm not going to use it, it was just something I noticed and is unimportant anyways.  Just curious to what it affected exactly!  Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk is the 'universal selector' and applies the style to *all* elements on the page. This code will reset everything to have no margins, padding or text-decoration.

[Universal selector on W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector)

Answer (score -1):

It is the universal selector, much like the '$' in jQuery. It is usually used in the reset

Comment: Not really sure how it relates to jQuery.

Comment: the "$" is a universal selector as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with Jan Dvorak on that.  the `$` in jQuery is used for variable declaration by default, while the `*` is not a declaration for variables in CSS at all, it's just a selector (to select all elements), kind of like a wildcard, without any words, or in SQL statements `SELECT *`.  Makes sense to me now!  Thanks guys!

Comment: This is nonsense. The universal selector in jQuery is *also* `*`. `$` is the jQuery function itself (or an alias thereof).